# Column mistakenly returning the key from HSTORE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, hstore

Ok, I have a weird one here.
In a Rails 4.0.13 application, I've added to a model:

`store_accessor :transcoding_meta, :state`

Looking at the schema of the model (SongVersion), `transcoding_meta`'s type is indeed `hstore`.

Note, there is also a `state` column on SongVersion, which is a string column.

```
s = SongVersion.ready.last
s.transcoding_meta
=> {"state"=>"finished"}

s.state
=> "finished"
```

When in fact, the state column in the database is saved as `"active"` as expected.

Why is Rails getting tripped up? Can I really not have an `hstore` key with the same name as an existing column? Seems it should know the diff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.store_accessor` is a macro that [defines accessors for hstore fields](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store/ClassMethods.html#method-i-store_accessor). As it's called inside the class body, generated accesstors override ones for DB columns provided by default by ActiveRecord. It looks that you cannot have store field and column with the same name in a model.

Comment: Might be better to link to the [official docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org) and the GitHub repository (if you need a specific version of Rails), APIDock is terribly out of date and apparently abandoned.

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing that out, @muistooshort. I didn't know APIDock is abandoned (too bad btw :|)

Comment: Thanks @mrzasa, appreciate that!

Comment: Yeah, a shame, the comments were handy but Rails 4.2.7 and Ruby 1.9.3 (!) is sort of ancient history.